# How to create an SVM with multiple features for classification?

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, scikit-learn, svm

I am writing a piece of code to identify different 2D shapes using opencv. I get 4 sets of data from each image of a 2D shape and these are stored in the multidimensional array featureVectors.

I am trying to write an svm/svc that takes into account all 4 features obtained from the image. I have been able to make it work with just 2 features but when i try all 4 my graph comes out looking like this.

[My Graph which is incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5thI.png)

My values for featureVectors are:

```
[[  4.00000000e+00   1.74371349e-03   6.49705560e-01   9.07957236e+01]
 [  4.00000000e+00   4.60937436e-02   1.97642179e-01   9.02041472e+01]
 [  1.00000000e+00   1.18553450e-03   3.03491372e-01   6.03489082e+01]
 [  1.00000000e+00   1.54552898e-02   8.38091425e-01   1.09021207e+02]
 [  3.00000000e+00   1.69961646e-02   4.13691915e+01   1.36838300e+02]]
```

And my Labels are:

```
[[2]
 [2]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]]
```

Here is my code for the SVM:

```
#Saving featureVectors to a csv file
values1 = featureVectors
header1 = ["Number of Sides", "Standard Deviation of Number of     Sides/Perimeter",
           "Standard Deviation of the Angles", "Largest Angle"]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(featureVectors)
my_df.to_csv('featureVectors.csv', index=True, header=header1)

#Saving labels to a csv file
values2 = labels
header2 = ["Label"]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(labels)
my_df.to_csv('labels.csv', index=True, header=header2)

#Writing the SVM
def Build_Data_Set(features = header1, features1 = header2):

    data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("featureVectors.csv")
    #data_df = data_df[:250]
    X = np.array(data_df[features].values)

    data_df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("labels.csv")
    y = np.array(data_df2[features1].values)
    #print(X)
    #print(y)

    return X,y

def Analysis():
    X,y = Build_Data_Set()

    clf = svm.SVC(kernel = 'linear', C = 1.0)
    clf.fit(X, y)

    w = clf.coef_[0]
    a = -w[0] / w[1]
    xx = np.linspace(0,5)
    yy = np.linspace(0,185)

    h0 = plt.plot(xx,yy, "k-", label="non weighted")

    plt.scatter(X[:, 0],X[:, 1],c=y)
    plt.ylabel("Maximum Angle (Degrees)")
    plt.xlabel("Number Of Sides")
    plt.title('Shapes')
    plt.legend()


    plt.show()

Analysis()
```

I have only used 5 data sets(shapes) so far because I knew it wasn't working correctly.

Comment: Your SVM code is correct - I think your plotting code is correct. Why are you plotting `X[:, 0], X[:, ]`? You should be plotting `plt.scatter(X[:, 0], y)`.

Comment: @mprat another example I found(i cant find the link again) said to do that, if i change it to plt.scatter(X[:, 0], y) I get the same graph but all the dots are now the same colour

Comment: Well at least the plot is now correctly plotting your y coordinate. If you want to change the color then do `plt.scatter(X[:, 0], y, c=y)`. But back to your original question - why do you think your SVM is not training properly? Typically in machine learning you have a test set and a training set. You train your SVM on your test set and measure your accuracy (analytically,  not visually) on a test set. You don't have a test set here, so why do you think your model is doing something wrong?

Comment: @mprat to be honest I am extremely new to machine learning and relatively new to coding in general. I was hoping that is how it works but obviously not. All the points have the largest angle as 0 which is incorrect. So are you saying that my code is actually looking at all four features, it just isn't plotting them correctly(or I don't think it is)?

Comment: Well first of all, you are never actually USING your learned function to predict anything. You are just plotting a line that has nothing to do with your model, and some points that are taken from your training features but have nothing to do with the actual class you are trying to predict. You are never running your model on data to see what it is actually predicting. To do that, you need to run your model on some data where you know what the correct result should be, and see the difference. This data should be data you have NOT used for training (i.e. called test data).

Comment: @mprat Could you post an answer here with what you think I should make my code?

Comment: I will love to post an answer when I understand your question. You asked how to create an SVM with multiple features, but your code already does that.

Answer (score 2):

The SVM part of your code is actually correct. The plotting part around it is not, and given the code I'll try to give you some pointers.

First of all:

> another example I found(i cant find the link again) said to do that

Copying code without understanding it will probably cause more problems than it solves. Given your code, I'm assuming you used [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-separating-hyperplane-py) example as a starter.

```
plt.scatter(X[:, 0],X[:, 1],c=y)
```

In the sk-learn example, this snippet is used to plot data points, coloring them according to their label. This works because in the example we're dealing with 2-dimensional data, so this is fine. The data you're dealing with is 4-dimensional, so you're actually just plotting the first two dimensions.

```
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], y, c=y)
```

on the other hand makes no sense.

```
xx = np.linspace(0,5)
yy = np.linspace(0,185)

h0 = plt.plot(xx,yy, "k-", label="non weighted")
```

Your decision boundary has actually nothing to do with the actual decision boundary. It's just a plot of y over x of your coordinate system. 
(In addition to that, you're dealing with multi class data, so you'll have as much decision boundaries as you have classes.)

Now your actual problem is data dimensionality. You're trying to plot 4-dimensional data in a 2d plot, which simply won't work.
A possible approach would be to perform dimensionality reduction to map your 4d data into a lower dimensional space, so if you want to, I'd suggest you reading e.g. [the excellent sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html#support-vector-machines-svms) for an introduction to SVMs and in addition [something about dimensionality reduction.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#decompositions)